# Find all one to one analytic functions that map the upper half plane $U$ onto itself (Hint: $\phi(z) = i\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ the unit disc onto $U$).

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find all one-to-one analytic functions that map the upper half plane $U$ onto itself (Hint: $\phi(z) = i\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ maps the unit disc onto $U$).

I am generally confused on how to approach such problems (ie: find the mapping from this to that). I have some strategies from linear transformations, like picking 3 points and solving the algebra to get $(a + bz) / (c + dz)$ to map properly. However, when finding "general" mappings, I really have no strategy other than guessing and checking.

First I am listing what I need to be true:

(1) if $z \in U$ then $f(z) \in U$

(2) $f(z_1) = f(z_2) \rightarrow z_1 = z_2$

Taking $w = f(z)$, then $u + iv = f(x+iy)$. When $y = 0$ ie I am working with the real boundary then I need it to map to the real boundary as well up to a real constant $\lambda$. Hence I am guessing the transformation must resembe the form:

$$f(z) = \lambda z$$

This intuitively makes sense, every element is scaled but remains in the respective $U$. How do I know this is the general case? More importantly, is there a method of thinking about this problem that lets me "see" the general case? Also, the purpose of the hint here is unclear.

Comment: $\phi^{-1}\circ f\circ\phi$ is an analytic bijection of the *open* unit disc to itself. I don't know enough complex analysis to say what that tells us, though

Comment: Maybe I can map to the unit sphere, modify as I please the unit circle (expansion), then map back?

Comment: Typically when studying Moebius transformations you learn that any invertible analytic map from $B(0,1)$ to itself has *exactly one specific form*, so use that.  In general when considering conformal maps between two simply connected domains you either deal with all of $\mathbb C$ or the unit disc (where in the latter case Riemann Mapping Theorem comes in useful though it isn't needed since you are explicitly given $\phi$ here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you must have seen in your course that one-to-one holomorphic self-maps of the unit disk are exactly maps of the form $f_{a,\theta}(z)=e^{i\theta} \frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$, for $\theta \in \mathbb R$ and $a \in \mathbb D$.

This is not completely obvious and it's an exercise in itself.

Using the hint, any one-to-one holomorphic self map of the upper half plane $\mathbb H$ must be of the form $\phi \circ f_{a,\theta} \circ \phi^{-1}$, so you have to compute that.